# Fit svg to any screen size; No scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Salute everyone,

I would like to fit an SVG plot to any screen size without it producing scroll bars. How can I do so? Please explain if it is possible to auto rezise/scale based off the screen size. For example, I want the content of an svg/whole page exactly fit any screen (shrinking or expanding) with no scroll bars.

The following is the CSS I have:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

////////// This is a related chunk. Secure data in the code

```
 <body>
<div id="tooltip">tooltip</div>
<svg width="100" height="100" ></svg>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 60,
        bottom: 110,
        left: 40
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,

    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please share svg file

Comment: check [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) and https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/svg-viewport-and-viewbox-for-beginners--cms-30844

Comment: Do you also want the SVG to retain its original aspect ratio, or to stretch to cover or be contained by the viewport?

Comment: @AKX stretch to cover the viewport. Thanks

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Use `100vh` for height and `100vw` for width instead of `%` in `body, html`
example:

```
body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and instead of setting height and width in `<svg>` tag, use this:

```
svg {
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

after this your `<svg>` will cover whole window.

Comment: This is helpful. How can I do this with the <svg> inside the body?

Comment: So you want this svg to be something like background?
How should it be placed on your page (draw it in paint or smth)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height and width of the svg to be 100VH and 100VW respectively:

CSS:

```
svg{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: This approach will crop the svg. I've tried it before. Remember, I want to zoom fit and scale to new screen without omitting any features.

Answer (score 0):

Your missed semicolon `;` after that `width: 100%;`

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
svg {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" ></svg>
```